# Wi-fi only avaliable sometimes on 20.04 and 21.10

Tags: wireless, internet, asus, iwlwifi

This is my first time ever posting a question and it is driving me insane.

On both 20.04 and 21.10, my Intel Wi-fi adapter works seemingly randomly. Sometimes it shows up and the internet is fine, and other times Ubuntu doesnt detect the Wifi card at all. Below is the result of querying the chipset:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

My motherboard is the ASUS ROG Stryx B550-I micro-itx if that helps.

This is a dual-boot configuration alongside Windows 11, which never has problems with the wi-fi card. Likewise, I have already tried the disable secure boot method to no avail.

I am a Linux noob and am trying my best to give it a fighting chance, but this issue is pushing me away due to its stubbornness and impedance of my work.

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

A note [from Linux-Hardware](http://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-2723-8086-0084):

> If you have a dual-boot machine with a recent version of Windows and start seeing problems during initialization of the WiFi device when booting Linux, the problem could be due to the “fast startup” feature on Windows.
>
> With this feature enabled, Windows don't really shut down the entire system, but leaves things partially running so you can start the machine faster again. Try to disable this option, on Windows 10 it should be in “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System Settings”. Select “Choose what the power buttons do” to access the System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”.

Multi-boot environments are often rife with problems that appear to be random but are almost always the result of inconsistent power states. If you must have the option to boot into both Windows and Linux via bare metal installations (as opposed to virtual machines), then it’s generally best to do a “Shut Down, Count to Ten, Boot” sort of process. Simply rebooting is not enough anymore.